# Using 32-bit Display buffer for android devices in Unity3d

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, gpu, framebuffer

When I build Android application in project settings checkbox "Use 32-but display buffer" is unchecked.
On most devices textures in application look correct, but on devices:

```
Nvidia 87 Shield Android 5.0.1 1920x1200 16 Gb 04136148010640008ffb 
Samsung Galaxy Tab 7.0 Plus 71 P6210 Android 3.2. 1024x600 RF2C100TB9W
```

textures looks bad(how 16bit textures - gradiented).

But when I check checkbox "User 32-but display buffer" textures look good on this devices.

Why on this devices textures look bad when I uncheck this checkbox, but on other devices look good?

Can I fix this without using this option? I known that build with this option doesn't working on some devices because It devices does not supported 32-bit framebuffer.

Comment: I don't fully understand why, yet, but color banding is a frequently reported issue when using low-bit depth buffers.

Comment: Maybe this is devices supported 16-bit buffer. From documentation - by default used 16-bit buffer, and "Android: added fallback to 24/32bit display buffer when 16bit display buffer is selected but not supported by the device."